# "Not a HASH reference" error in perl while creating a multi-dimensional hash with its key able to store multiple values

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to create a multidimensional hash with its keys as an array so that the same keys can store multiple values, and is not overridden.

Below is the code snippet:

```
my %hashR;
my @RelDiv = qw(15.4 dev ques 15.4 dev ques2 15.4 dev2 ques1 15.4 dev2 ques2 
                15.2 dev3 ques2); 
while (my $RName = shift @RelDiv) {
    my $ProStr = shift @RelDiv;
    push @{$hashR{$RName}}, $ProStr;
    my $BName = shift @RelDiv ;    ## Working file till here (tried printing the values)
    push @{$hashR{$RName}{$ProStr}}, $BName;   ###### Error on this line
}
```

The structure I want is as follows:

```
{
      '15.4' => {
                   
                   'dev' => [
                                'ques',
                                'ques2'
                            ]
      
                  'dev2' => [
                               'ques1',
                               'ques2'
                             ]
                  
                },
       '15.2' => {
                   'dev3' => [
                                'ques2'
                            ]             
                }
```

};

But, I am getting an error "**Not a HASH reference at file1.pl line**". Can anyone please help in resolving the error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you forget to put `qw(` at the array assignment `@RelDiv`? Because that is not valid code. You're not trying to write code without `use strict; use warnings` are you? That's a bad idea.

Comment: Added the structure. Don't want any hardcoding. And what id I need to create another layer of hash with its keys as array

Comment: Keys of an hash need to be unique. This is not a possible structure

Comment: Made some changes in the structure. Can you please help on that?

Comment: This is a simple enough thing to create, but the way you have phrased it, first building an array with data, then turning the array into a hash of hash of arrays is the wrong way around. How did you get the data to the array? Start there.

Comment: I got the data from some manipulation of the script written above what I am intending to write here. It is actually a1000 lines of script, and data is manipulated and processed and then has been pushed into an array via "push" . But, does it matter where/how the data into an array has come?

Comment: @PPP Well, yes, its easier if you don't have to splice elements off an array. You have to use such awkward methods. Just build the hash right away and skip the middle step with the array.

Comment: How can i make such structure right away in a hash? Assuming these elements which i mentioned in array are coming from command-line options. I guess, array has to be created if we want to store two or more values for 1 key

Comment: @PPP If you want me to see a comment, you have to tag me with the `@TLP` tag. It is just as easy to make a hash as it is to make an array. Instead of `push @array, $key; push @array, $val1; push @array, $val2;` just do `push @{ $hash{$key} }, $val1, $val2;` I'd have to know what your code looks like to say exactly how you would need to work it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an array reference when you do this:

```
push @{$hashR{$RName}}, $ProStr;
# means: $hashR{$RName} = [ $ProStr ]
```

Then you try to use it as a hash ref when you do this:

```
push @{ $hashR{$RName}{$ProStr} }, $BName;   ###### Error on this line
#                    ^^^-- here
```

Its hard to tell what you want the structure to look like, so I can't really help you with recommendations. Perhaps if you explained what you are trying to achieve, I could help.

---

With the new structure update, this is a simple way to do it

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
my @RelDiv = qw(15.4 dev ques 15.4 dev ques2 15.4 dev2 ques1 15.4 dev2 ques2 15.2 dev3 ques2); 

while (@RelDiv) {
    my ($RName, $ProStr, $BName) = splice @RelDiv, 0, 3;
    push @{ $hash{$RName}{$ProStr} }, $BName;
}
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Output (the data structure):

```
$VAR1 = {
          '15.4' => {
                      'dev2' => [
                                  'ques1',
                                  'ques2'
                                ],
                      'dev' => [
                                 'ques',
                                 'ques2'
                               ]
                    },
          '15.2' => {
                      'dev3' => [
                                  'ques2'
                                ]
                    }
        };
```

The below criticism remains, however. There is something you're not telling about your data collection, and this solution with `splice` from an array is not very good. You should go back one step and talk about your data collection.

Its not a very good way to create a hash, though. If you are just going to assign a list of values to an array at the start, instead assign it to the hash right away and don't do this strange conversion into another structure. Or if you are, as I suspect, reading from a file, again, create the hash structure right away. If you give more detail, I can provide better recommendations.

Comment: Thanks. Actually this was only something I was looking for. And comment above by @Georg Mavridis (Keys of a hash need to be unique) made it a little more easier to understand. Instead of splice, i would be using shift ( while (my $RName = shift@RelDiv) {
    my $ProStr = shift @RelDiv;
    my $BName = shift @RelDiv;
    push @{ $hash{$RName}{$ProStr} }, $BName;
}
); and will access the keys/values in a similar way. Main thing I was looking was push "@{ $hash{$RName}{$ProStr} }, $BName;"

Comment: @PPP Splice or shift, your method still depends on having sets of three elements, all in all, an awkward method. And it doubles the amount of memory needed, which can be quite bad if you have big batches of data. Yes, hash keys are unique. This can be both a benefit and a drawback. To a human, `"foo"` looks pretty much the same as `" foo"`, but in a hash they would be two different keys. So if you are building a hash from an input source, you must be sure it is uniform.